# MonoGame Winforms - Load Content

Tags: winforms, monogame

I am creating some tools for MonoGame using Windows Forms. I'm using the tutorial that you can found on the Xbox Live forums. I implemented the Graphics Device but I don't know how to Load Content. Can someone help me?

I'm using MonoGame 3.4 and Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load content you'll need the `ContentManager`. The ContentManager's constructor in Monogame 3.4 takes an `IServiceProvider` instance and resolves the `IGraphicsDeviceService` to get the `GraphicsDevice` instance.

Since you have already implemented the `GraphicsDevice`, all you need to do is implement the `IGraphicsDeviceService` and `IServiceProvider` .

I'll implement just the necessary for the `ContentManager` to work.

First implement the `IGraphicsDeviceService` to return the `GraphicsDevice`.

```
public class DeviceManager : IGraphicsDeviceService
{
    public DeviceManager(GraphicsDevice device)
    {
        GraphicsDevice = device;
    }
    public GraphicsDevice GraphicsDevice
    {
        get;
    }
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DeviceCreated;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DeviceDisposing;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DeviceReset;
    public event EventHandler<EventArgs> DeviceResetting;
}
```

Then implement the `IServiceProvider` to return the `IGraphicsDeviceService`

```
public class ServiceProvider : IServiceProvider
{
    private readonly IGraphicsDeviceService deviceService;

    public ServiceProvider(IGraphicsDeviceService deviceService)
    {
        this.deviceService = deviceService;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return deviceService;
    }
}
```

and finally you can initialize a new instance of the `ContentManager`.

```
 var content = new ContentManager(
                  new ServiceProvider(
                       new DeviceManager(graphicsDevice)));
```

Don't forget to add a reference to `Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content`.